# How to read MS Outlook Calendar in Android programmatically, in offline mode

Tags: android, outlook

I want to write an Android app that reads calendar events in Microsoft outlook in offline mode but I'm not sure if it is even possible. I have written code to read Outlook calendar through REST APIs provided but the problem is 1- I need to have a connection for it to work, 2- It does not work when the app is in the background (in service).

I have researched a lot but I can't seem to find a good document or sample code that does this. Does someone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "MS Outlook Calendar"? As far as I know MS Outlook is only available on MS Windows systems. Which certainly is not a platform where you can execute android apps.

Comment: I'm using the outlook/office365 RESTE API to get the calendar entries for the user in an Android app. The URL request is: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview. You can install Outlook app on your Android and I'm trying to read the database from that app, that is stored on the device locally